# Issues with Regex on newline terminated contents

Tags: java, regex

I have the following String:

```
String script = "%NAME%\n"
                + "adwaita-icon-theme\n"
                + "\n"
                + "%VERSION%\n"
                + "3.20-1\n"
                + "\n"
                + "%DESC%\n"
                + "Adwaita icon theme\n"
                + "\n"
                + "%URL%\n"
                + "http://www.gnome.org\n"
                + "\n"
                + "%ARCH%\n"
                + "any\n"
                + "\n"
                + "%BUILDDATE%\n"
                + "1458859575\n"
                + "\n"
                + "%INSTALLDATE%\n"
                + "1461498688\n"
                + "\n"
                + "%PACKAGER%\n"
                + "Jan de Groot <jgc@archlinux.org>\n"
                + "\n"
                + "%SIZE%\n"
                + "24542208\n"
                + "\n"
                + "%REASON%\n"
                + "1\n"
                + "\n"
                + "%GROUPS%\n"
                + "gnome\n"
                + "\n"
                + "%LICENSE%\n"
                + "GPL\n"
                + "\n"
                + "%VALIDATION%\n"
                + "pgp\n"
                + "\n"
                + "%DEPENDS%\n"
                + "hicolor-icon-theme\n"
                + "gtk-update-icon-cache\n"
                + "librsvg\n";
```

This is the raw data from file:

```
%NAME%
adwaita-icon-theme

%VERSION%
3.20-1

%DESC%
Adwaita icon theme

%URL%
http://www.gnome.org

%ARCH%
any

%BUILDDATE%
1458859575

%INSTALLDATE%
1461498688

%PACKAGER%
Jan de Groot <jgc@archlinux.org>

%SIZE%
24542208

%REASON%
1

%GROUPS%
gnome

%LICENSE%
GPL

%VALIDATION%
pgp

%DEPENDS%
hicolor-icon-theme
gtk-update-icon-cache
librsvg
```

I need to capture the contents withing the `%` and anything under it. I'm having issues with termination. I tried this:

```
\\%(.*)\\%\\n((?s:.*))
```

And it captures the first group correctly, but then captures the next one also as a part of the first expression. So with this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\%(.*)\\%\\n((?s:.*))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(script);

while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

I get this:

```
run:
NAME
adwaita-icon-theme

%VERSION%
3.20-1

%DESC%
Adwaita icon theme

%URL%
http://www.gnome.org

%ARCH%
any

%BUILDDATE%
1458859575

%INSTALLDATE%
1461498688

%PACKAGER%
Jan de Groot <jgc@archlinux.org>

%SIZE%
24542208

%REASON%
1

%GROUPS%
gnome

%LICENSE%
GPL

%VALIDATION%
pgp

%DEPENDS%
hicolor-icon-theme
gtk-update-icon-cache
librsvg

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

The first one gets capturer properly, but the rest gets captured as group 2 of the first expression. I know this because in the output there should not be any `%` characters.

How to capture the contents under the `% { ... } %` tags as a group, and the contents inside the tags as another.

I need this for strict detection. Using Java 8 on Linux.

Comment: Not sure, but perhaps, [`"%([^%]*)%\r?\n([^\r\n]*(?:\r?\n(?!\r?\n)[^\r\n]*)*)"`](https://regex101.com/r/oR9rM1/2) can help. The part after `%([^%]*)%` just matches anything up to the double linebreak. It does not depend on whether `%` appears in the contents or not.

Comment: Try `"\\%(.*)\\%\\n(.*)"`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `DOTALL` `?s` flag in your second group, so `.` will match anything including line feeds and the second group will contain the rest of the file.

Your second group should sometime hold multiple lines (for example for the `%DEPENDS%` block), however it should never match up to the next `%`. So instead of using a `DOTALL`ed `.`, I would suggest using the negated class `[^%]` which should match line feeds without the need of the `DOTALL` flag but will not match the next `%`.

Your regex would then become `\\%(.*)\\%\\n([^%]*)`.
Note : I removed a pair of parentheses in the end because I saw no need for it.
Note 2 : your regex may be a little more efficient as `\\%([^%]*)\\%\\n([^%]*)`.

See it in action [here](http://ideone.com/MKjzU8).